# redirect_via_turbolinks_to undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, turbolinks

I'm getting this error when I try to use redirect_via_turbolinks_to in my controller

```
undefined method `redirect_via_turbolinks_to' for
```

I extracted this method from the doc:

```
Triggering a Turbolinks visit manually

You can use Turbolinks.visit(path) to go to a URL through Turbolinks.

You can also use redirect_via_turbolinks_to in Rails to perform a redirect via Turbolinks.
```

I'm using turbolinks '1.3.1' in rails 3.2.14

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks.visit(path) can be used in your JS/Coffee assets or within some embedded JS:

```
$ ->
  $(document).dontBeNaughty()

jQuery.fn.dontBeNaughty = ->
  $(".ReportsHistory").on "click", ->
    action = $(this).data('url')
    Turbolinks.visit("/reports?" + action)
```

You can use the `redirect_via_turbolinks_to` in your controller instead of rendering a template.

More information can be seen in the [source of turbolinks here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/blob/a43e26f7b0b5302c1e2131bb920c46551231f700/lib/turbolinks.rb#L50-L60):

Comment: I'm already using redirect_via_turbolinks_to in my controller, and I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this, `redirect_via_turbolinks_to` is deprecated  in favor of `redirect_to url, turbolinks: true`

Source: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md